# Missing spacing between the bottom "Highly active question" banner and the page buttons

Tags: bug, design, protected-questions

If a question has a "Highly active question" banner and >1 page of answers, the page-switching buttons touch the banner.

Looks like some spacing is missing here.

See [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/8233/55490) for an example. Scroll to the bottom.

[image: pic]

Comment: Note that if you don't see the banner because you have enough rep, you can view it by opening the page in a private/incognito window. Or you can just log out.

Comment: Apparently, the element with the `js-post-notice` class is missing an `mt24` class here and thus lacks proper `margin-top` ([amended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejqki.png) example). Seems like they only accounted for notices appearing on [the top of posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwoGg.png)

Comment: I don't understand why the banner position changes basing on the user reputation. Seeing the banner on the top, users who cannot answer the question would avoid scrolling the page to answer it.